# Why was the answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

I have answered a question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/622736/377375). I don't understand why the answer was deleted. Correct me if I am wrong.

> [image]

Comment: I'm not a mod not a 10k'er so I can't see it, but was the answer a link only one? Those usually tend to be removed, specially if they go through the [Low Quality Posts](http://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts).

Comment: It would of ended up in the late posts queue or somethin, and was probably much more noticeable as u posted it more than twice. If you post one answer, and link from the other questions in comments thats better than(/more preferred/not as noticeable as) 3 copy n paste answers

Answer (score 6):

You have used the same answer repeatedly.  This is regarded as "noise" on Ask Ubuntu.

You've posted the same answer to 2 different questions, is the reason for deletion.

[How to transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-setup-a-lan-between-ubuntu-and-windows/622736#622736)

[How do I set up file sharing between two Ubuntu laptops on my wireless network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156169/how-do-i-set-up-file-sharing-between-two-ubuntu-laptops-on-my-wireless-network/622734#622734)

Comment: I request moderators to have an eye on [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100790/how-to-enable-file-sharing-between-two-pcs) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156169/how-do-i-set-up-file-sharing-between-two-ubuntu-laptops-on-my-wireless-network/622734#622734) and check user One Zero's answers. Rules must be the same for all users, high reputed or low. Atleast he could have merged that into a single answer.

Comment: Why is it noise if it correctly answers the question? You've just deleted one of my answers for this reason, too. Sure, it's the same answer, but it's the right answer to both questions.

Comment: @TimothyZorn Then it should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Ok, I've marked the question as a duplicate. Is there a way to merge the two questions and their answers?